# Error: package <package name> does not exist - but I know it does?

Tags: java, gradle

I am getting an error with a project I am trying to build - and I have absolutely no idea what is going on :

I am bringing in this class :

```
import com.company.module.pojo.MyPojo;
```

Ok, that is straight forward, and in intelliJ, I can even cmd + click and go directly to that class, I KNOW it is there, and I know intelliJ knows it is there.

then I do a build... and I get this...

```
error: package com.company.module.pojo does not exist
```

What? Why? How is this happening? :(

I am tagging gradle in this question, as I am from the maven world, and this whole mess could be down to me not having a clue about gradle, I guess.

I know that this is usually caused by the class not existing (or a typo in the import) but I know that to be all in place, so I am stumped here.

Comment: Where does that class come from?

Comment: The class can exist and be there but it might not be a dependency in your gradle build.

Answer (score 0):

Add it as a module dependency.

File
Project Structure
Project 
Modules
Dependencies 
Green plus sign on the right.
Choose correct directory